# sql : How is data validation done through Stored procedures?

Tags: sql, oracle

> " Stored procedures are typically used for data validation or to 
>   encapsulate large, complex processing instructions that combine several SQL queries."

Says this Oracle [reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm). So can someone help me understand by putting in real world examples how stored procedures are used fro data validation ?

Comment: well, I am certainly not an expert and that's why I'd rather leave a comment. Isn't true that you could write your business logic in stored procedures as the main access point to your tables, and by this you could validate data before actually persisting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data validation occurs because to pass data into a stored procedure, it's done via parameters which are explicitly set to Oracle data types (or user defined types, which are also based on Oracle data types).  Only validation of the data type occurs - more in-depth validation has to be constructed if necessary (IE: checking for decimals in a NUMBER data type).  Parameterized queries are generally more safe from SQL injection, but it really depends on what the parameters are and what the query is doing.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE example (IN_VALUE NUMBER) IS

 BEGIN

   SELECT t.*
     FROM TABLE t
    WHERE t.column = IN_VALUE;

 END;
```

In this example, submitting a VARCHAR/string will result in an error - anything other than what NUMBER supports will result in an error.  And you'll get an error if the IN_VALUE data type can't be implicitly converted to the data type of TABLE.column.

A stored procedure encapsulates a transaction, which is what allows complex processing instructions (meaning, more than one SQL query).  Transaction handling (IE: having to explicitly state "COMMIT" or "ROLLBACK") depends on settings.

Comment: I was waiting for your answer ;)

Comment: so which means data validation is done at database level by stored procedure, in addition to client side validation ?. Do we need to have validations at both layers ?

Comment: @SuperMan: Yes, validate in both layers.  Always validate at the database as though there is no client side validation.

Answer (score 4):

Validation can mean a number of things, and can be done in the database in various ways:

- Column datatypes are themselves a form of validation: NUMBER columns accept only valid numbers, etc.
- Primary key, unique and foreign key constraints perform validation
- Check constraints perform other simple one-row validations such as:

  - END_DATE > START_DATE
  - SALARY > 0
  - JOB = SALESMAN OR COMMISSION IS NULL

However, there are more complex validation rules that cannot be enforced by any of the above, such as:
 - SALARY <= (SELECT max_sal FROM config_table)
 - emp.start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date of the department they are assigned to

There are various ways to enforce these rules, including database triggers, but often the preferred method is to create a stored procedure, often known as an "API" to perform the validation and action e.g.

```
PROCEDURE insert_emp (...) IS
    ...
BEGIN
    -- Validate
    -- 1) Salary less than max
    SELECT max_sal
    INTO   l_max_sal
    FROM   config;
    IF p_sal > l_max_sal THEN
        error_pkg.raise_error ('Salary is too high');
    END IF;
    ...
    -- Insert
    INSERT INTO emp (...) VALUES (...);
END;
```

The application can then just call this procedure instead of performing the update directly and all the necessary validation will be performed.  In fact, the application would probably **have** to call this procedure - direct insert into the table would probably be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

In an ideal world, your DBMS of choice would be relationally complete, allow you to write constraints of arbitrary complexity and support multiple assignment to allow your database to be updated at all times (i.e. without deferring or disabling constraints) using simple statements. In the real world we have SQL.

An ideal SQL product would be Full SQL-92 Standard compliant: support `CREATE ASSERTION` (schema-level constraints), allow subqueries in `CHECK` constraints and support the deferring of constraints within a transaction to enable your database to be updated without disabling constraints. Sadly, Oracle has not yet attained this level of functionality. Therefore, in the real world we have to sometimes resort to procedural code to "manage" updates while maintaining data integrity.

Consider for example a true one-to-one relationship, being common enough, with the business rules as follows:

> A database contains details of
>   employees and projects in three
>   relvars: EMP, PROJ and EMP_PROJ. Every
>   project must be have at least one
>   employee and every project attachment
>   must refer to an existing project.
>   When a project is created at least one
>   employee must be simultaneously
>   attached to it.

In Oracle, you can't write an `ASSERTION` or `CHECK` to enforce the inter-table constraints, so the ability to defer constraints is of little consequence in this case.

One approach that can work to write a `PROCEDURE` with appropriate parameters to create a project and assign one employee to the project. Such a procedure would, in this order (pseudo code):

1) begin transaction;

2) insert into `PROJ`;

3) insert into `EMP_PROJ`;

4) Test for data that would fail the notional constraints e.g.

```
EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
          FROM PROJ
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT * 
                             FROM EMP_PROJ
                            WHERE EMP_PROJ.project_code = PROJ.project_code
                          )
       );
```

5) If the test finds illegal data then rollback otherwise commit the transaction.

If the constraints bite then the transaction is rolled back and data integrity has been maintained (though you perhaps would want to handle such a validation failure more gracefully :)

A similar procedure would be required to remove an employee from a project to prevent the scenario when the last-remaining assigned employee is removed from the project (should the employee removal be prevented or should the project be deleted? ask your designer :)

Because data integrity can only be ensured by executing such procedural code, it is convenient for everyone to encapulate it in a `PROCEDURE` object in the database then grant 'execute' privileges on the `PROCEDURE` to users (rather than grant enhanced privileges on the underlying tables). To force a group of users (e.g. end user applications) to only use the `PROCEDURE` to update the data, their update privileges on the underlying tables should be revoked. This may require further 'helper' functions to be provided e.g. to assign employees to a project and to delete a project. If you buy into the "all database access through stored procs" school of thought you would be doing this anyway.

Comment: +1 even though steps 1 and 5 do not belong in a stored procedure but in the calling environment, in my opinion.